# What's the other side of Inheritance?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a child inherits something from their parent, we say that the child *Inherited* that something. That's the child's perspective.

What is the word from the parent's perspective?

I've thought of *bestow upon*, or *to transfer something*, or to *have something inherited by*, but none of those convey the exact meaning - except for the last one of course, but that's way too cumbersome.

Note that I'm thinking of the general form of inheritance, as could be used, for example, in Object-Oriented programming; not necessarily limited to any biological children and parents, although answers specific to that situation are most welcome.

Comment: 'Pass on' seems the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want "bequeath." It's not commonly used, but it means, "to pass on (property, etc.) to a beneficiary." As in,

(From *Oxford English Dictionary*, "bequeath" 4.)

["To make a formal assignation of (property of which one is possessed) to anyone...b. so as to pass to the recipient after one's death: To 'leave' by will."](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.library.ubc.ca/view/Entry/17847?rskey=dBlV0w&result=2#eid)

Use: [property] is bequeathed to [person/organization]
e.g. "Her entire fortune was bequeathed to her cats."

Comment: That sounds much better than _grant_

Comment: 'Bequeath' would sound very strange / quirky used of say blue eyes.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see a better option for inheritance, including genetics, except "pass down." (Not that there's anything wrong with "pass down," as long as OP will accept a phrasal verb too).

Comment: Of course, the word is more commonly used in the noun form "bequest".

Comment: Nothing wrong with phrasal verbs :)

Comment: While _bequeath_ is a good enough answer for most everyday purposes, in formal legal contexts the term is not used if the property is 'real' (land and buildings). Also, it should be noted that, as the quotation from OED makes clear, it is applicable only when a will is involved.

Answer (score 6):

In scientific writing, [genes](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topic/gene-inheritance-and-transmission-23) and traits, both [genetic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895717799000631) and [cultural](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040580913000907), are *transmitted* to those that *inherit* them.

> The gene for red–green color blindness is *[transmitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness)* from a color blind male to all his daughters who are heterozygote carriers and are usually unaffected.

A genetic trait can also be *passed from parent to child*:

> Red/green colour blindness is *[passed from mother to son](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/inherited-colour-vision-deficiency/)* on the 23rd chromosome, which is known as the sex chromosome because it also determines sex.

Or *passed down*:

> Congenital color blindness is usually inherited as a genetic trait [*passed down*](http://evec.com/color-blindness) from mother to son.

Treasured objects and family lore may also be *[passed down](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lore)* over several generations, but only real objects are usually said to be inherited.

If you inherit tangible property from your grandmother, it is because she *[bequeathed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bequeath?s=t)* it to you, made a *[bequest](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bequest?s=t)*, *[willed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/will?s=t)* it *to* you, or *[left](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/leave?s=t)* it *to* you [in her will].

> [S]he *[left](https://www.oldtownhome.com/2012/4/2/Dealing-with-the-Loss-of-a-Family-Heirloom/)* a small five stone gold mother's ring *to* my mother-in-law as one of the few items in her estate.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to use the verb [will](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will):

> 2 a : to dispose of by or as if by a will : bequeath
>
> ```
> willed his entire estate to his son
> ```
>
> b : to order or direct by a will
>
> ```
> willed that her property be divided among her children
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another one a few minutes after posting this. I'll add as an answer as it seems correct, unless proven otherwise by the number of downvotes!

[**grant**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grant) might work:

> to transfer or convey, especially by deed or writing:
>   to grant property.

Answer (score 0):

*Bequeath* is probably the best answer in terms of biological parents & children, but it doesn't really work in a situation like Object-Oriented Programming. The term that seems to work well in both situations is *pass down.*

Answer (score 0):

"Bequeath" is the legal-jargon term; "give" or "leave" is the ordinary verb. Even legal documents, though (where they must get paid by the word!) say "give and bequeath". It's a holdover from the days when lawyers wanted to be sure beyond a doubt that nobody misunderstood what they meant -- so they would use both the Latinate and the common everyday terminology.